# Why we set property Hibernate.Dialect?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have persistence.xml file in my project and in this file one property is being set, so I am curious, Why it is being set? What it does?

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although basic SQL is a standard, different databases use different data types for certain things outside the standard, have different methods of quoting identifiers, etc. The *dialect* is hibernate's way to abstract away from these differences - think of it as the translation layer between HQL and the right SQL for each database.

Answer (score 0):

so that we can take advantage of database specific features.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint to JPA to take advantage of your database and its dialect. JPA can find out this by itself but sometimes it is better to fix the dialect (e.g. to fix it for Oracle 10g even when using Oracle 11g).